# how to check whether a function contains try and catch using NDepend?

Tags: c#, ndepend, cqlinq

Need to create a custom rule in NDepend using CQLinq to check whether a public method code block is inside try and catch.

The following gives all the public methods:

```
from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsPublic
select m
```

Is there a feature in NDepend that can be used to traverse code inside a method or find a particular string?

Comment: Unfortunately by now this is not something reachable through CQLinq. You can still refactor a but, call a method inside the try/catch, and then check this method is calling the other method, but of course this solution is not optimal.